Bug in javascript code for website transitions on scroll
Below is the js code which is running various animations on a webpage. As you scroll there is 4 text/picture sections that transition onto the page when a trigger point is hit.


$(document).ready(function() {
  var reapplyAnimation = function(element, animationClass) {

    void element.offsetWidth;

    $(element).addClass(animationClass);
  };

  $('.blob').each(function() {
    var blobElement = this;
    var animated = false;
    var section = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section');
    $(section).addClass('hidden-on-load');
    
    new Waypoint({
      element: blobElement,
      handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction == 'down' && !animated) {
          
          $(section).removeClass('hidden-on-load');
          reapplyAnimation(blobElement, 'animated-fade-rotate');
          
          var relatedImage = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section').find('.image-container img')[0];
          $(section).removeClass('hidden-on-load');
          reapplyAnimation(relatedImage, 'animated-slide-rotate');

          var textContainer = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section').find('#text-container')[0];
          $(section).removeClass('hidden-on-load');
          reapplyAnimation(textContainer, 'animated-fade-in-slide-in-right');

          animated = true;
          this.destroy();
        }
      },
      offset: '45%' // Trigger point
    });
  });
});



It has been through many iterations so far to make the animation smooth and fade in from opacity 0 to 1 without firsth flashing (hence void element.offsetWidth to load the page again). At the moment on scroll only the first section correctly appears, the other three don't appear at all.

Don't know much about jQuery, but you might get an answer quicker if (1) you mention jQuery in the question itself and (2) convert the code to a runnable code snippet (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) so that people can scroll and immediate replicate your problem.

I'm sorry about that, it should be a snippet now. That's on not knowing much about jQuery either, or Stack for that matter - new user!
